# HOW TO ADD NEW TEXTVIEW WHEN NEW DATA IS ADDED

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to add new textview whenever new data is saved. I am using intent to pass the data from adding activity to primary activity. In my main activity I am using linear layout in vertical alignment. But when I am adding new data, it is updating the old textview.

I need to show data entered in vertical alignment in linear layout.

Comment: You need to share your current code.

Answer (score 1):

you not share your code so i am not sure this will help but in my case it work, you need add Dynamically textViews to your  linearLayout i think

```
final int N = 10; // total number of textviews to add

final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[N]; // create an empty array;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    // create a new textview
    final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);

    // set some properties of rowTextView or something
    rowTextView.setText("This is row #" + i);

    // add the textview to the linearlayout
    myLinearLayout.addView(rowTextView);

    // save a reference to the textview for later
    myTextViews[i] = rowTextView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

initialize golbal `TextView x;`

inside OnCreate

```
x = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
String newtext;
x.setText(x.getText()+"\n"+newText);
```

Comment: How does this relates to OP's query?